# Fun project -- can you hook flash?

Tags: javascript, flash

So my wife is hooked on playing bejeweled on Facebook.  Whenever I watch her play (and she's pretty good) I think man I bet I could write a pretty sweet algorithm that would put up a really good score.

So more than anything, I guess I need to know, if there is anyway to observe the UI hooks in Flash from either in the browser with JavaScript or from outside the browser entirely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to look at a different technology to auto play the game. A .NET or Java app can easily auto play the game for you. Your app would have to take screenshots and the app pattern matches to figure out what pieces are which. The app can than fire off the click commands that are needed to play the game.